# Response.Redirect from a page inside a folder of web solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications, httpresponse

In my solution i have a folder FIRE in which i have a page.I am using respose.redirect to handle my error to another page Error.aspx.
I am writing

```
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    //DisplayError(ex);
    Session["ExceptionDetails"] = ex;
    Response.Redirect("ErrorInformationDetails.aspx");
}
```

but getting **error**

> resource not found /FIRE/ERROR.aspx not found.

but for other pages which are in main directory its working fine

Comment: use false with Response.Redirect("ErrorInformationDetails.aspx,false");

Answer (score 2):

Always use root operator (~) to avoid such errors:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Fire/Error.appx");
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Response.Redirect("~/Fire/Error.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This code.This Can reduce a RoundTrip Process of Web Request if cursor goes to Exception Block.

```
Response.RedirectPermanent("~/Administration/Masters/SearchThought.aspx");
```